# Can getText() in Selenium (Python 3) be used to read nested HTML tags?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am reading data from Wikipedia with **Selenium** in Python 3 and need advice on reading the text encoded in **nested HTML tags**.

I tried using the `getText()` function but am either using the wrong syntax or the wrong function.

For example, this *line of code*

```
        location=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="location"]').getText()
```

does not retrieve any data whatsoever,

whereas *that line of code*

```
     location=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="location"]').get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

gives me results like this one:

```
The <a href="/wiki/Dalmatia" title="Dalmatia">Dalmatian</a> island of <a href="/wiki/Hvar" title="Hvar">Hvar</a>, esp. its largest city, also called <a href="/wiki/Hvar_(town)" class="mw-redirect" title="Hvar (town)">Hvar</a>.
```

I can, of course, strip the output from HTML tags, but I hope there is a better solution.

Comment: Python instead of .getText() it should be .text

Comment: Thanks so much, .getText() is just for Java, I figure.

Comment: also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium